# Url redirect in htaccess from old url to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting my existing old URL to new URL links, I have tried using the following  code

```
Redirect 302 /about-us-company http://xyz./pharmaceutical-manufacturing-company
```

It is redirecting to new URL but at the end of the new URL the previous URL link is also appending how can I remove the previous one

**Output:**
    http://xyz./pharmaceutical-manufacturing-company?/about-us-company

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^about-us-company    http://www.example.com/pharmaceutical-manufacturing-company? [L,R]
Redirect 301 /products http://www.example.com/pharmaceutical-products?
Redirect 301 /csr http://www.example.com/corporate-social-responsibility?
Redirect 301 /research http://www.example.com/pharmaceutical-formulation-development?
Redirect 301 /news http://www.example.com/latest-news-events?
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} about-us-company/$
RewriteRule ^about-us-company/ http://xyz.pharmaceutical-manufactuturing-company [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

For single url use this code

```
Redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.yournew.com/new.htm
```

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example1.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Answer (score 0):

Redirect directive appends rest of the old url to its destination target. You can use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` to get rid of the trailing old path

```
RedirectMatch 302 /about-us-company http://xyz./pharmaceutical-manufacturing-company
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` at the end of target to prevent Query string from being appending like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us-company    http://example.com/pharmaceutical-manufacturing-company? [L,R]
```

Comment: I do not require ? at the end of the url as the SEO url should not be used in this way @Mohammed Elhag

Comment: @SairamDuggi did you tried it ? this will not be in URI , the new URI will be as it is and without previous Query String , this only to prevent appending and will not be in new URI , did you understand ?

Comment: Redirect 301 /about-us-company http://example.com/pharmaceutical-manufacturing-company? i have tried in this way @Mohammed Elhag

Comment: @SairamDuggi did you clear browser cache ? what is the result?

Comment: yes I have cleared the cache and tried in different browsers but the same issue repeats @ Mohammed Elhag

Comment: @SairamDuggi get updated code , clear browser cache the test

Comment: No its not working @Mohammed Elhag I have placed my htaccess file please check

Comment: @SairamDuggi show me your code? did you have any other rules ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168083/discussion-between-sairam-duggi-and-mohammed-elhag).